# Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag (download report using dompdf )

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to download my html report into pdf file using dompdf, but I'm getting this error:

> Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::$first_name

here's my controller code so far:

```
public function monthlypayrollProcess(Request $request) 
{
    $monthlypayrolls = Driver::join('driver_payables', 'driver_payables.driver_id', '=', 'drivers.id')
                            ->join('driver_payable_details', 'driver_payable_details.driver_payable_id', '=', 'driver_payables.id')
                            ->select(
                                'drivers.id',
                                'drivers.first_name',
                                'drivers.last_name',
                                'drivers.nric', 
                                'drivers.join_date', 
                                'drivers.basic_salary',
                                'drivers.uniform_size',
                                'driver_payables.total_working_hours',
                                'driver_payables.take_home_pay'
                            )
                            ->where('driver_payables.payroll_period_id', $request->payroll_period_id)->get();

    if ($monthlypayrolls->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, 'No Data');
    }
    $view = view('reporting.monthly_payroll.detail')->with(compact('monthlypayrolls'));
    return parent::render($view, null, null);
}

public function downloadMonthlyPayrollReport(Request $request)
{
    $monthlypayrolls = $this->monthlypayrollProcess($request);
    $isPdf = true;
    $view = 'reporting.monthly_payroll.pdfview';
    $pdf = PDF::loadView($view, compact('monthlypayrolls', 'isPdf'))->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

and here's my pdf view blade code so far :

```
<div class="table-responsive text-center">
<table class="table table-hover" id="datatable" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Driver Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">NRIC</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employment Type</th>
            <th class="text-center">Hired Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Basic Salary</th>
            <th class="text-center">Uniform</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total Working Hours</th>
            <th class="text-center">Take Home Pay</th>                             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($monthlypayrolls as $monthlypayroll )
            <tr>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->first_name }} {{ $monthlypayroll->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->nric}}</td>
                <td>{!! DriverEmployedType::getString($monthlypayroll->employed_type) !!}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->join_date}}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->basic_salary }}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->uniform_size}} {{$monthlypayroll->uniform_quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->total_working_hours}}</td>
                <td>{{$monthlypayroll->take_home_pay}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The `monthlypayrollProcess()` method returns a Response view, then you are assigning it to another variable

```
$monthlypayrolls = $this->monthlypayrollProcess($request);
```

Finally in your view

```
<td>{{$monthlypayroll->first_name }} {{ $monthlypayroll->last_name}}</td>
```

Something wrong with your logic, the method probably should return an object not a view. The method should be something like that:

```
public function monthlypayrollProcess(Request $request) 
{
    $monthlypayrolls = Driver::join('driver_payables', 'driver_payables.driver_id', '=', 'drivers.id')
                            ->join('driver_payable_details', 'driver_payable_details.driver_payable_id', '=', 'driver_payables.id')
                            ->select(
                                'drivers.id',
                                'drivers.first_name',
                                'drivers.last_name',
                                'drivers.nric', 
                                'drivers.join_date', 
                                'drivers.basic_salary',
                                'drivers.uniform_size',
                                'driver_payables.total_working_hours',
                                'driver_payables.take_home_pay'
                            )
                            ->where('driver_payables.payroll_period_id', $request->payroll_period_id)->get();

    if ($monthlypayrolls->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, 'No Data');
    }
    return $monthlypayrolls;
}
```

Comment: sorry, what should i change.

Comment: What is the role of this function `monthlypayrollProcess()`?

Comment: sorry, what do u mean by role ?

Comment: to join 3 tables and select data.

Comment: why does it return a view? It should return the object directly. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129735/discussion-between-andrew-vanusi-and-mina-abadir).

Answer (score 0):

I had this very issue when trying to retrieve data as a `response->json($myObject)` and then iterating through it with a foreach with blade in the view.

I solved it by just returning the object "as is" (i.e. `return $myObject` instead of `return response->json($myObject)` ).

Hope this helps!